# Displaying Data Table And Submiting Form In One Page Struts

Tags: spring, jsp, error-handling, struts

I'm new in Struts, currently I'm using struts 1.3 to build simple Contact application

I want to display data table contains contact list from the database, in the same page I want to create a form for creating new contact and then insert it to database.

I'm using Spring bean and hibernate to do database operation and logic. So here is my flow, my action class will call spring bean, and the spring bean will call dao classes for database operation do some logic, then my action class will put the list into request object named contactList, then in jsp file I'm iterate it using logicLiterate tag.

Displaying the table and submiting all works fine, but when I do validating in ActionForm, and I want to display the error message, I have an error 500. This is because the jsp cannot find attribute named contactList in the request object, because if there is an error in ActionForm classes, Struts not calling the method at my Action class that will read the database and put it into the request object. I can try calling the spring bean in my ActionForm, but I'm afraid it not appropriate, because if there is no error then I will call the spring bean twice for the same work. What do you suggest me to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad not to read the doc carefully, now i understand that action tag in struts-config.xml have "input" attribute, this attribute specifies the physical page to which the request has to be forwarded if there is an error.

In my case, i just have to specified the input attribute to current path (eg. /contacts.do, etc) so the Action class can do its Action method.

Please note that, this request is forward requuest, not redirect.

Comment: yes, you have to add only input attribute to your action tag (input=“/form/exampleXML.jsp”). Also, just a small recommendation. You can use display tag for displaying list. It will surely help you a lot instead of iterate tag. http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/ Please note that I am in no way related to displaytag